# How to delete and replace last line in the terminal using bash?

Tags: bash, replace, terminal, line

I want to implement a progress bar showing elapsed seconds in bash. For this, I need to erase the last line shown on the screen (command "clear" erases all the screen, but I need to erase only the line of the progress bar and replace it with the new information).

Final result should look like:

```
$ Elapsed time 5 seconds
```

Then after 10 seconds i want to replace this sentence (in the same position in the screen) by:

```
$ Elapsed time 15 seconds
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

echo a carriage return with \r

```
seq 1 1000000 | while read i; do echo -en "\r$i"; done
```

from man echo:

```
-n     do not output the trailing newline
-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes

\r     carriage return
```

Comment: `for i in {1..100000}; do echo -en "\r$i"; done` to avoid the seq call :-)

Comment: When you use things like "for i in $(...)" or "for i in {1..N}" you are generating all elements before iterating, that's very inefficient for large inputs. 

You can either take advantage of pipes: "seq 1 100000 | while read i; do ..." or use the bash c-style for loop: "for ((i=0;;i++)); do ..."

Comment: Thanks Douglas and tokland - athough the sequence production wasn't directly part of the question I've changed to tokland's more efficient pipe

Comment: My matrix printer is completely messing up my paper. It keeps jamming dots on the same piece of paper which is no longer there, how long does this program run?

Comment: how to do the same with php and stdout?

Answer (score 225):

The carriage return by itself only moves the cursor to the beginning of the line.  That's OK if each new line of output is at least as long as the previous one, but if the new line is shorter, the previous line will not be completely overwritten, e.g.:

```
$ echo -e "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\r0123456789"
0123456789klmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

To actually clear the line for the new text, you can add `\033[K` after the `\r`:

```
$ echo -e "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\r\033[K0123456789"
0123456789
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: This works really well in my environment. Any knowledge of compatibility?

Comment: In Bash at least that can be shortened to `\e[K` instead of `\033[K`.

Comment: @The Pixel Developer: Thanks for trying to improve it, but your edit was incorrect.  The return must happen first to move the cursor to the beginning of the line, then the kill clears everything from that cursor location to the end, leaving the whole line blank, which is the intent.  You put those at the beginning of each new line, similarly to Ken's answer, so that it is written on an empty line.

Comment: @DerekVeit I was using zshell which might have different behaviour. I'll have to test my hypothesis.

Comment: Just for the record, one can also do `\033[G` i.o. `\r` before `\033[K` though obviously `\r` is much simpler. Also http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html gives more details than Wikipedia and is from xterm developer.

Comment: Also, the portable (and somewhat less arcane) version of ` $'\033[K'` is `"$(tput el)"`.

Answer (score 31):

Derek Veit's answer works well as long as the line length never exceeds the terminal width. If this is not the case, the following code will prevent junk output:

before the line is written for the first time, do

```
tput sc
```

which saves the current cursor position. Now whenever you want to print your line, use

```
tput rc
tput ed
echo "your stuff here"
```

to first return to the saved cursor position, then clear the screen from cursor to bottom, and finally write the output.

Comment: Wierd, this does nothing in terminator. Do you know if there are compatibility limitations?

Comment: Note for Cygwin: You need to installed package "ncurses" to use "tput".

Comment: Hm... Seems not to work if more then one line is in the output. This doesn't work: `tput sc # save cursor

echo '' > sessions.log.json
while [ 1 ]; do
    curl 'http://localhost/jolokia/read/*:type=Manager,*/activeSessions,maxActiveSessions' >> sessions.log.json
    echo '' >> sessions.log.json
    cat sessions.log.json | jq '.'
    tput rc;tput el # rc = restore cursor, el = erase to end of line
    sleep 1
done`

Comment: @Nux You need to use `tput ed` rather than `tput el`. @Um's example used `ed` (perhaps he fixed it after you commented).

Comment: FYI, Here is the list of tput commands [Colours and Cursor Movement With tput](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html)

Comment: It looks like this saves and restores the “graphical” position of the cursor, not its “logical” position. If the cursor initially lies on the last graphical row of the terminal window, and a line of text is written which spans on two graphical rows, then the display moves up by one row while the recorded graphical position stays the same (_i.e._ on the last row of the display). So we’ll end up jumping one row below where we should (observed with urxvt). I hope I’m clear. Fascinating how hard getting some piece of TUI correct is hard…

Comment: Also, it may be worth mentioning that `tput ed` is a more costly operation than `tput el` and hence (at least in my terminal, urxvt) it causes the text to blink annoyingly.

Answer (score 23):

The \033 method didn't work for me. The \r method works but it doesn't actually erase anything, just puts the cursor at the beginning of the line. So if the new string is shorter than the old one you can see the leftover text at the end of the line. In the end tput was the best way to go. It has other uses besides the cursor stuff plus it comes pre-installed in many Linux & BSD distros so it should be available for most bash users.

```
#/bin/bash
tput sc # save cursor
printf "Something that I made up for this string"
sleep 1
tput rc;tput el # rc = restore cursor, el = erase to end of line
printf "Another message for testing"
sleep 1
tput rc;tput el
printf "Yet another one"
sleep 1
tput rc;tput el
```

Here's a little countdown script to play with:

```
#!/bin/bash
timeout () {
    tput sc
    time=$1; while [ $time -ge 0 ]; do
        tput rc; tput el
        printf "$2" $time
        ((time--))
        sleep 1
    done
    tput rc; tput ed;
}

timeout 10 "Self-destructing in %s"
```

Comment: That clears the whole line indeed, problem it twinkles too much for me :'(

Answer (score 17):

In case the progress output is multi line, or the script would have already printed the new line character, you can jump lines up with something like:

`printf "\033[5A"`

which will make the cursor to jump 5 lines up. Then you can overwrite whatever you need.

If that wouldn't work you could try `printf "\e[5A"` or `echo -e "\033[5A"`, which should have the same effect.

Basically, with [escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php) you can control almost everything in the screen.

Comment: The portable equivalent of this is `tput cuu 5`, where 5 is the number of rows (`cuu` to move up, `cud` to move down).

Comment: @Maëlan Thanks! Would you happen to know how to clear ("reset") line after running `tput cuu 5`?

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve it by placing carriage return `\r`.

In a single line of code with `printf`

```
for i in {10..1}; do printf "Counting down: $i\r" && sleep 1; done
```

or with `echo -ne`

```
for i in {10..1}; do echo -ne "Counting down: $i\r" && sleep 1; done
```

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to clear the previous line, the following might do the trick.

```sh
printf '\033[1A\033[K'
```

For multiple lines, use it in a loop:

```sh
for i in {1..10}; do
    printf '\033[1A\033[K'
done
```

This will clear the last 10 lines.

Comment: One thing I'd like to add is that you can combine the pattern into one; depending on your needs. For example, if you want to delete 2 lines, you can avoid using it in a loop with this statement - `printf '\033[1A\033[K\033[1A\033[K'`. Use `echo -e '\e[1A\e[K\e[1A\e[K'` if the `echo` supports `-e` flag and cleaner to you.  BTW, `echo` is a builtin function in most shells, so depending on the shell you're using, the `echo` might or might not support the `-e` flag.

Answer (score 5):

Use the carriage return character:

```
echo -e "Foo\rBar" # Will print "Bar"
```

Comment: This answer is the simplest way. You can even achieve the same effect using: printf "Foo\rBar"

Answer (score 0):

### *Multiline solution*

---

In comment referencing [@Um's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2757684) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18916357/17342313), [@Maëlan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4615179) correctly identified that `tput sc` saves only the ***graphical*** position, not **logical**. You can clearly see it when you run the script, while being at the last line of a terminal. The printed text behaves like it is not being cleared at all.

---

To solve it, as well as make the solution more optimised, I've made the following `clearLastLines` function:

```bash
function clearLastLines() {
    local linesToClear=$1

    for (( i=0; i<linesToClear; i++ )); do
        tput cuu 1
        tput el
    done
}
```

Passed as a parameter the number of lines to clear.

Example usage:

```bash
echo 'Text to be deleted 1.'
echo 'Text to be deleted 2.'

clearLastLines 2
echo 'New text.'
```

---

#### Notes:

- It works only when the number of lines to delete is known (shouldn't be hard to implement it when it is unknown).
- Would be great if anyone could actually verify whether the solution is actually better for terminals like `urxvt`, etc. (as mentioned by [@Maëlan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4615179)).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using backslash in your `echo`'s, you can use `tput`. To simplify this you can create a function:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function consoleoneline {
    # Start process and save all outputs in a temporary directory
    tput sc # save current cursor in console
    local PIPE_DIRECTORY=$(mktemp -d)
    trap "rm -rf '$PIPE_DIRECTORY'" EXIT

    mkfifo "$PIPE_DIRECTORY/stdout"
    mkfifo "$PIPE_DIRECTORY/stderr"

    "$@" >"$PIPE_DIRECTORY/stdout" 2>"$PIPE_DIRECTORY/stderr" &
    local CHILD_PID=$!

    # Replace all outputs with a leading "›"
    # `tput` allows to reset the cursor to the previous line
    sed "s/^/`tput rc;tput el`› /" "$PIPE_DIRECTORY/stdout" &
    sed "s/^/`tput rc;tput el`› /" "$PIPE_DIRECTORY/stderr" >&2 &

    # Wait command has exited, remove temporary directory and reset cursor
    wait "$CHILD_PID"
    rm -rf "$PIPE_DIRECTORY"
    tput ed
}

consoleoneline bash -c 'echo 1 && sleep 1 && echo 2 && sleep 1 && echo 3'
```