# How can I modify a line which I have already echo it to the screen

Tags: bash

When we download something or install software via Terminal, we always see a number show the progress to us.
The number is changed, but it still in the same line.
How can I do in the bash?

I'm a new basher, help!

Comment: http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/A_progress_bar_%28gauge_box%29 - 2 seconds on google (this one is a fancy TUI variety).

Comment: Use a carriage return http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388090/how-to-delete-and-replace-last-line-in-the-terminal-using-bash

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1508589/45249) to [How can I erase the current line printed on console in C ?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1508490/45249) may help. It is about [VT100 escape codes](http://www.climagic.org/mirrors/VT100_Escape_Codes.html). In bash, `printf "\x41"` outputs `A`.

Comment: I was just about to comment about ANSI escape codes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `echo -n`.

More informations on [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628327/how-to-show-and-update-echo-on-same-line).

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to use `\r` instead of `\n` at the end of the line:

```
echo -n " 50% complete."$'\r'; sleep 1; echo "100% complete."
```