# Print rising number in same place

Tags: python, printing, terminal

I would like to print the numbers from 1 to 100 to the terminal with `print`. But I want only one number to be displayed which is steadily incremented.

I know that I can print in the same line by putting a `,` behind the `print` statement, but I want to clear the line and print to it again. How can I do this?

---

Okay, I tried to solve it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897359/output-to-the-same-line-overwriting-previous-output-python-2-5) by adding `end='\r'`

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time

for x in range(100):
    print(str(x), end='\r')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

but that just does nothing.

Comment: this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388090/how-to-delete-and-replace-last-line-in-the-terminal-using-bash

Comment: and upon further search, this question was already asked and answered here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897359/output-to-the-same-line-overwriting-previous-output-python-2-5

Comment: How are you running the script? For example in IDLE this might not be possible.

Comment: I'm not running it at all. I was just wondering how to print like that.

Comment: does that answer your question vicco ? If you wrote a piece of code share so we can see where you're getting at and help.

Comment: @vicco on IDLE doesn't work for me, but in terminal it does: `for i in range(10): print '{: 3d}'.format(i), '\r', ; time.sleep(0.1)` -- python 2.7.10

Comment: Very strange, it does work when I execute it in LiClipse, but it does neither work in terminal nor in Idle.