# Introduce ANSI codes into a stream

Tags: bash, sed, stdout

I want any stdout to display on one line only. Each successive line should overwrite the last.

Typically, I would do

```
echo -ne "Overwrite me. \033[0K\r"
```

But now I want to pipe the output, and since echo is not a filter I need to use sed or something e.g.

```
cat story.txt | some.sed.like.util.for.replacing.$.with.\033[0K\r
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete and replace last line in the terminal using bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388090/how-to-delete-and-replace-last-line-in-the-terminal-using-bash)

Answer (score 1):

`sed` can't be used since `sed` will always append a newline to it's output. You need to use a `while` loop in the shell:

```
while read -r line ; do
    echo -en "\r\033[0K${line}"
    sleep 1
done < story.txt
```

Comment: `echo -en "\r\033[0K${line}"` — otherwise the longest line so far is always displayed "under" the current line.