# Progress bar + ETA on same line with pv command

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, pv

### Intro

I'm using the `pv` command in a pipe to show a progress bar. I tried it with a simple counter:

```
for (( i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i++ )); do sleep 1; echo $i; done | pv --progress --line-mode --size 100 --eta --timer
```

This works fine, but I'd like the progress bar to show on the same line. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2388107/741217) explains how to do that.

So I tried this:

```
for (( i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i++ )); do sleep 1; echo $i; done | >&2 echo -en "\r"; pv --progress --line-mode --size 100 --eta --timer
```

It stays on one line, but now it doesn't update the ETA anymore.

### Question

How can I get the ETA to update too?

### Update

Now that iBug [answered the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47813799/741217) from the previous section, I realized I had one more requirement that's relevant: the `stdout` needs to be preserved so it can be used in the next pipe. In my specific case I need to write the result to a file (i.e. `> some-file.txt`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're typing the wrong command.

```
for (( i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i++ )); do sleep 1; echo $i; done | >&2 echo -en "\r"; pv --progress --line-mode --size 100 --eta --timer
                                                                               ^
```

There's a semicolon before `pv`, so you're actually running it on stdin/stdout, which is your terminal. You should group the extra `echo` and `pv` to let it read from the `for` loop:

```
for (( i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i++ )); do sleep 1; echo $i; done | (>&2 echo -en "\r"; pv --progress --line-mode --size 100 --eta --timer)
```

Why this isn't the case for the first command? It is because the whole `for do done` clause is treated as a single command, so its result correctly gets piped to `pv`. In the second command, however, the result is piped to `echo`. You know, that `echo` doesn't read anything from stdin.

Because `pv` directs stdin to stdout, the numbers also gets output to the terminal, which mixes up with the indication to stderr. To suppress the nornal output, redirect it to `/dev/null`, so the final command is

```
for (( i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i++ )); do sleep 1; echo $i; done | (>&2 echo -en "\r"; pv --progress --line-mode --size 100 --eta --timer) > /dev/null
```

If you want to redirect the output to a file, just change `/dev/null` at the end of the command.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean, but I tried this on the command line and now it updates progress on new lines again (like my first example). Is there an essential bit missing?

Comment: @RolfW. I added a pair of parentheses around `echo ; pv`

Comment: I noticed, but I now see my comment wasn't clear; What I actually meant is that I don't fully understand the principle behind what you were explaining, so I wasn't able to get it right by myself after your suggestion. When I try your example as-is, it [prints each progression on the next line again](http://prntscr.com/hnrq47), like the first code example in my question. What I'm after is that the progress bar + percentage + ETA updates on the same line. Do you know how to make the code work like that?

Comment: That's it :) Thank you!

Comment: For anyone interested, I had one more requirement of writing the stdout to a file at the end of the pipeline: `for (( i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i++ )); do sleep 1; echo $i; done | (>&2 echo -en "\r"; pv --progress --line-mode --size 100 --eta --timer > /dev/null) > temp.txt`. This solution suppresses stdout, so a workaround is needed: `for (( i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i++ )); do sleep 1; echo $i >> temp.txt; echo "$1"; done | (>&2 echo -en "\r"; pv --progress --line-mode --size 100 --eta --timer > /dev/null)`

Comment: @RolfW. I wouldn't care if you add this into your question (and I'll update my answer). But generally asking other questions in comments is a bad practice.

Comment: It was meant as a comment, since I also wrote a solution. But you're right. I added a section `Update` to my question. While writing it, I also realized that a better solution is much more obvious than my workaround :)

Comment: @RolfW. Your solution is a bit messed up. First you're calling `echo "$i"` twice in each `for` loop, which is redundant, and there's even a typo. Second there's no need to create a copy of output to the file as you can redirect `pv`'s stdout to the target, which is already established in my answer.