Is there a way to replace a line of output with a new value in a bash script?
Ok, now, I've seen answers to this question for C++ and PHP and so on, but I want to do this using bash. Also, there is another question like mine, but it has been answered with echo -e as the primary upvoted answer, which - according to some responses to my question - is less than desirable. There is, way at the bottom, an answer similar to mine (using printf) but it's "in the weeds." Lots of messy examples there, too. That being said, what I want to accomplish is:
I want to print a line "45 minutes left" and then replace it with "44 minutes left" after 60 seconds. I've tried using \r but it just prints "\r" - I'm using echo do output this text. This is my code:
echo "Sleeping for 45 minutes..."
for mins in {45..1}
do
  echo "$mins minutes left..."
  sleep 60
done

which prints:
45 minutes left...
44 minutes left...
43 minutes left...

and so on. But I want it to update on the same line, changing the number of minutes on the same line of text. Is there any way to do this in bash? I've tried:
echo -n "$mins minutes left...\r"

and
echo -n "$mins minutes left..."
echo -n "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b" #(obviously there's a more elegant way to print a certain number of backspaces but just doing it this way as an example)

but it just prints out the \r and \b's as text and doesn't actually move the cursor to the beginning of the line.
Is there an alternative to echo that will do this?

This question is similar to: How to delete and replace last line in the terminal using bash?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Don't use echo for this as the string you're trying to print contains escape sequences and never add any options to echo (e.g. -e or -n) to try to work around its issues, use printf instead - see why-is-printf-better-than-echo.
Specifically, your script should look like this:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dur='45'

printf 'Sleeping for %d minutes...\n' "$dur" >&2

for (( mins="$dur"; mins > 0; mins-- ))
do
  printf '\r%d minutes left...\t\t' "$mins" >&2
  sleep 60
done
printf '\n' >&2

I'm redirecting the status messages to stderr as that's typically what you'll want to do with such messages so they don't get mixed in with any "real" desired output from your script.
You could use for mins in $(eval echo {"$dur"..1}) instead of for (( mins="$dur"; mins > 0; mins-- )) if you wanted to retain the sequence expression {45..1} syntax for some reason but IMO that's needlessly complicated and fragile compared to the simple loop I'm using above.

while not so obvious here, you might need padding on the right to blank the previous text when it is longer. I'm inclined to mark this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388090/how-to-delete-and-replace-last-line-in-the-terminal-using-bash

@jhnc - good point, I didn't test it for longer than 5 seconds so didn't notice the double-digit -> single problem. I stuck a couple of tabs on the end of the line to take care of that, assuming the OP doesn't have a massive starting duration.

@jhnc the problem with that other question is that the accepted answer and the most upvoted answer both use -e which isn't a good dea, so directing people to that question is also directing them to bad answers and the good answers there are hidden in the weeds and unlikely to ever overtake the bad ones.

fair enough, although there's some useful stuff in those weeds

The padding is not necessary if you use \033[K at the beginning of the printf string and then put the \r at the end, which clears out the whole line and then prints the new output, and finally puts the cursor at the beginning of the line. I did check out the other question and my version of echo - in the man pages - does not say anything about -e being implemented.

@JacobJackson how portable is \033[K? I saw it in answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388090/how-to-delete-and-replace-last-line-in-the-terminal-using-bash but didn't want to introduce it here unnecessarily if it wasn't extremely portable since a couple of extra blanks or tabs would handle the issue.

There are almost certainly multiple versions of echo on your system, one a builtin and another an external command. You're probably calling the builtin version which apparently does support -e but looking up the man page for the external version which doesn't.

@EdMorton I'm not sure... I've tried it on macOS and Ubuntu Linux (latest versions, LTS for Ubuntu) and it works great on them. Not sure about older versions.

I'm just going to leave it as-is as what I have will work in every terminal on every Unix box.

worked on FreeBSD, too - just had to install bash. Thanks for your solution, @EdMorton, I'll give that a try as well

\033[K has a precise definition for ANSI-compatible terminals; \r depends on how your terminal chooses to handle U+000d.

@chepner thanks for the info. The suggestion was to also print \033[K though, not replace \r with it, so adding \033[K can only make it less portable and so I think I'll just leave it as-is since the code will work fine without it and I slightly prefer in general producing fewer escape sequences in case anyone wants to capture the output for analysis later.

@EdMorton Yeah, I think assuming an ANSI-compatible terminal technically throws portability out the window anyway :) I was going to mention tput in my previous comment as well, to generalize the script from ANSI-compatible terminal to any terminal supporting the correct capability, but tput itself isn't really portable either, so... :shrug:

Scratch that: tput is part of POSIX; could have sworn I looked for it there once and didn't find it.

Well, turns out all I needed to do was replace echo with printf - I just had to search for "an alternative to echo in bash" - lol.

or add -e to your echo command. See: help echo

Don't use echo -e (or add any other option to echo), it just makes your script even less portable. Even on the same system echo -e will do different things depending on how it is called, options it was compiled with, environment variable settings, the version of the shell you're running, etc.  If a plain echo doesn't do what you want then just use printf.
